# FSM in Scala for an Issue/Ticket Management System

Tags: scala, akka, fsm

Hi I wanna code my own Ticket Management System (TMS) and I think that a FSM is the best way to realize ticket states and transitions. In a TMS there are a lot of tickets that are in different states and those ticket states have to be persisted into my database.
So to run that FSM I have to load the state, perform the transistion (like notifying owner, agents etc) and save the new state into my database.

My question is: I read a little about Akka FSM which might be the solution to my problem, but I didn't find anything about my state persistence.
Does anyone have a hint for me on how to proceed?

Comment: Your google-fu is weak: http://www.lightbend.com/activator/template/akka-sample-persistent-fsm There are quite a lot of other relevant looking hits for "akka fsm persistence"

Comment: Yeah, right after I wrote my question I did just that! :) So my Google Fu is just slow... ;)  Thanks for your hint!